# How to determine if a raster layer covers a polygon layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, extents

I have a raster and a polygon layer. In my application I always want the raster layer to cover all the polygon layer. How can that be determined? Is it possible to find out from boundary extent of these layers?

In this example, I want to give a warning to the user that the raster layer does not cover the polygon layer.

[image: Screenshot of raster not covering polygons]

I am using .Net technology in ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: What is the picture for? would you like to extend this raster to cover up all polygons? or is it just an example for a raster that does not cover all polygons

Comment: @Erica, can I follow the following procedure :                    I will take extent from raster and polygon, and then compare the upper-right and lower-left point ... and then take the decision that polygon layer is inside the raster layer ...

Comment: @Monir I believe so -- I just posted an answer below. I haven't ever done this in ArcObjects (I do Python primarily) but the method should work!

Comment: @dof1985, the image is for just an example, in which case I will notify user that , your raster layer does not cover all the polygon layer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the question of overlap (does Feature 1 cover Feature 2 or not) can be answered by looking at the feature extent. This is the case whether you're working with a raster and a polygon, two sets of polygons, two rasters, etc.

If these four criteria, then Feature 1 covers Feature 2:

- XMin1 < XMin2
- XMax1 > XMax2
- YMin1 < YMin2
- YMax1 > YMax2

If not, the Feature 2 is larger (in at least one dimension) and therefore isn't covered.

---

I do not personally program in ArcObjects or .Net, but [the IEnvelope reference might be what you're looking for](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnvelope2_Interface/002m0000016m000000/) in your particular implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I will try and inform you the result ...thanks :)